# Проблема с открытием файла

Tags: c, файлы, структуры, динамические-массивы

столкнулся с странной для меня проблемой:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

char name_of_file[256] = "";

int AO_files = 1;

struct File
{
    FILE* stream = NULL; 
};

char * get_file_name(int index)
{
    snprintf(name_of_file, sizeof(name_of_file), "map%d.txt", index);
    return name_of_file;
}

bool open_file(File*& array_of_files, char* file_name, int index)
{
    if (index < 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    fopen_s(&array_of_files[index].stream, file_name, "wb+");
    if (array_of_files[index].stream == NULL)
    {
        return  false;
    }
    return true;
}

bool create_new_file(File*& array_of_files, int& size)
{
    if (size == 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    size++;
    File* new_array_of_files = new File[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; ++i)
    {
        new_array_of_files[i].stream = array_of_files[i].stream;
    }
    new_array_of_files[size - 1].stream = NULL;
    delete[] array_of_files;
    array_of_files = new_array_of_files;
    if (open_file(array_of_files, get_file_name(size - 1), size - 1))
    {
        printf_s("%s map%d.txt %s", "Файл",size - 1,"Успешно открыт!\n");
        return true;
    }
    printf_s("%s map%d.txt %s", "Файл",size - 1, "Открыть не удалось!\n");
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    File* array_ = new File[AO_files];
    open_file(array_, get_file_name(0), 0);
    for (auto i = 0; i < 599; ++i)
    {
        create_new_file(array_, AO_files);
    }

    for (auto i = 0; i < 600; ++i)
    {
        fclose(array_[i].stream);
    }

    delete[] array_;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Почему-то успешно открывается только 508 файлов, следующий за ним 509 не открывается, это влечёт за собой то, что глобальная переменная AO_files (AO = amount of) растёт и следующий за ним файлы тоже не открываются. Почему такое происходит и как можно исправить?
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: А зачем вам столько одновременно открытых файлов? 8-0 Насколько я помню, в  VC++ максимум - 512, что ли, что очень похоже на ваш предел (ведь уже открыты cin, cout, cerr, clog)...

Comment: Дело в том, что я реализую алгоритм Виртуального Хеширования, это программа, показывающая суть ошибки. В Виртуальном хешировании борьба с коллизиями решается методом цепочек, так вот, файл изначально разбивается на 10 блоков по 10 элементов в каждом. И если место в каком-то блоке занято полностью, то есть свободных цепочек не осталось, создаётся новый файл с теми-же правилами и новая запись добавляется уже в него. Поэтому столько файлов и создаётся. Если изначально сделать так, чтобы цепочек в блоке было, например, 40, то столько файлов не потребуется и программа будет работать.

Comment: В вопросе стоит тег С, однако приведен код на С++. Так что используйте `fstream`.

Comment: Создается - ладно, но **открытыми** их держать-то зачем?! Хотя и сам подход вызывает большие сомнения...

Comment: @user7860670 - а это сейчас так можно писать - мол у нас чистый си, но чуточку плюсико выпирает. Не первый раз уже такое вижу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В студии есть предел в 512 открытых одновременно файлов https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/setmaxstdio?view=msvc-160

Его можно чуточку увеличить

```
_setmaxstdio(8192);
```

Но не больше.

Если хочется больше - тот тут видимо нужно переходить на линукс, там ulimit по умолчанию дает 1024, но можно увеличивать, как минимум до миллиона я доходил (открытых дескрипторов).

Связанный вопрос - [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870173/is-there-a-limit-on-number-of-open-files-in-windows).

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Comment: Только это ограничение не на количество одновременно открытых файлов вообще, а на количество открытых через `FILE`. Ну и по-хорошему тут можно немного подправить код, так как никакой реальной необходимость держать открытыми кучу файлов у ОПа нет.

Comment: Если у Вас си, то как бы вариантов не много. Да, можно использовать апи конкретной операционной системы, но...